# textAccessible labels RGraph Bar not plotted correctly in hidden nav tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, rgraph

I am creating Horizontal Bar Graphs on a HTML5 webpage using JS [RGraph](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/hbar.html). The text of the labels turns out very blurry unless you set the [textAccessible attribute](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/accessible-text.html) to **true**. This attribute uses absolute coordinates on the page.

My issue ([text labels plotted on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEViM.png)) arises when I try to create a graph hidden underneath a navigation tab (I use bootstrap and custom CSS code). The tab needs to be active (style="display:flex") on page load for the graph to be [drawn correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXIsV.png), but it is not the main tab and therefore cant be given the active attribute. If the tab is not active on page load (style="display:none") the labels are not drawn correctly (as there are no coordinates yet I assume).

Is there any way to work around this issue? I've tried to ReDraw the Graph whenever the tab turns active, but I couldn't get it to work. I've added part of the code below:
html code with tab **inactive**
`<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-5-tab">
<canvas id="hbar1" width="450" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>
</div>`

html code with tab **active**
`<div class="tab-pane fade active" id="nav-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-5-tab">
<canvas id="hbar1" width="450" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>
</div>`

JS code of HBar Graph
`hbar1 = new RGraph.HBar({
          id: 'hbar1',
          data: data1,
          options: {
             backgroundGrid: false,
             xaxis: false,
             xaxisScaleMax: 100,
             xaxisScaleDecimals: 1,
             xaxisScale: false,
             labelsAboveUnitsPost: '%',
             colors: ['#019b91'],
             yaxisLabels: labels1,
             yaxisTickmarksCount: 0,
             labelsAbove: true,
             textAccessible: true
          }
  }).wave();`

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the canvas before you draw the chart (every time the tab is shown).

```
RGraph.reset(hbar1.canvas);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helped me further, but not quite there. I played around with the reset code, but it still only functions properly after clicking the tab a <strong>second</strong> time. 
I am now trying to implement a wait for tab-content to load function, but it returns canvas is null when I do this. 

I'll keep trying as there are more questions around here with that issue.

Regards, Marijn